# In SSIS, have a destination accept multiple inputs

Tags: ssis

I have a target table where I need to input 3 columns. Problem is, all 3 columns come from different sources.

[image].

I need to get a column from each red outlined source and map them into the yellow outlined destination.

As far as I have managed to, Union All, Merge or Merge Join only serve to join Rows, and no other component takes more than one input. I need to map a column from three different sources into the same destination, at the same time.

Thanks.

Edit: More detail:

Each of the outlined components in red returns a table. I need to map one column from each of them to a column in the destination (outlined in yellow). However, the destination can only take one input, ie, can only be connected to by one of the elements in red. I need to connect all three to the destination, mapping a column from each of them to the respective column in the destination table.

Say the destination has a table with the columns yellow_X, yellow_Y and yellow_Z. ISO Lookup returns a table with the columns red_X, red_A, red_B, the multicast returns a table with columns red_Y, red_C, red_D, and the other lookup returns red_Z, red_E, red_F. I want to map red_X from the left lookup into yellow_X, red_Y from the multicast into yellow_Y and red_Z from the rightmost lookup into yellow_Z. Is it possible? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Welcome! Is there more information you can provide? Code or screenshots? This question might be hard to answer with the current amount of detail

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more specific in the original post.

Comment: Why are you performing a multicast? You should just be able to link all of the components directly. Note, when going from one lookup to another, set the precedent to 'Match Found' (or something to that effect). If you have to split the data flows with a multicast then you will need to bring them back together with either a Merge Join or a Union All - it depends on the requirement. From there you will have one input to the destination component.

Comment: not able to understand the question. Please give a structure of 3 sources and destination. so I can understand the relation between them and possible way

Comment: I have solved it by removing the multicast and simply chaining the lookups one after the other. Turns out it was simpler than I thought. Any way, if anyone has an answer to the original question, I'd still appreciate it, in case I do actually need to do it. Merges or unions do not work in this case, as they join Rows, not Columns. Thanks for the help.